# Problems undrawing objects - Processing

Tags: tree, processing, processing.js

Looking through the documentation, it looks like noFill(); and noStroke(); are all I should have to call to "undraw" my object. Right now, on click, I am displaying a child node of my tree, but on another click on the parent, I want those children to collapse and "undraw". Could anybody let me know what might be going wrong here? Much appreciated. Running in javascript.

MAIN SKETCH:

```
//SFD Tree Visualization
//Austin Slominski 2014

Node root;
Node current;
XML data;

void setup(){
    root = new Node();
    data = loadXML("nodes.xml");

    size(750,750);
    smooth(true);
    background(255);

    loadChild(root, data, null);
    current = root;
}

void loadChild(Node node, XML data, Node parent) {
    XML title = data.getChild("title");
    String xmlTitle = title.getContent();
    node.title = xmlTitle;

    XML[] XMLchildren = data.getChildren("child");
    node.children = new Node[XMLchildren.length];

    for(int i=0;i<XMLchildren.length;i++){
      node.children[i] = new Node();
    }

    //DEBUG
        println("Current Node: " + node.title);
      if(parent!=null){
        println("Parent: " + parent.title);
        node.parent = parent;
      }
      if(node.children!=null){
          println("Number of Children:" + XMLchildren.length);
      }
        println("");

    for (int i = 0; i < XMLchildren.length; i++) {
      loadChild(node.children[i], XMLchildren[i], node);
    }
}

void draw(){
    current.display();//starts inactive, null collapsed

    if(current.collapsed == false) {
          for (int i = 0; i < current.children.length; i++) {
        current.children[i].display();
    }
    }

}

void mousePressed(){
    current.clickedActive();

    for (int i = 0; i < current.children.length; i++) {
      current.children[i].clickedActive();
    }
}
```

NODE CLASS:

```
/* <a rel="nofollow" href="/two/profile/pjs">@pjs</a> font="Junction-light.otf"; */
PFont f;

class Node {

      Node parent;
      Node[] children;
      public String title;

      int x=120;
      int y=140;
      int tWidth;
      int tHeight;
      int titleColor = 0;
      float textSize=70;
      public boolean active = false;
      public boolean collapsed = true;

    Node(){
      f = createFont("Junction-light.otf",100,true);
      textFont(f,textSize);  
    }

    void display(){
      if(parent == null) {
        fill(titleColor);
        text(title,x,y);
        noFill();
      } else {
        if(parent.collapsed == true){
          noFill();
          noStroke();
          text(title,x,y);
        }else{
          fill(titleColor);
          text(title,x,y);
          noFill();
        }
      }


      tHeight = textAscent();
      tWidth  = textWidth(title)+8;
      //rect(x,y-tHeight,tWidth,tHeight);
    }

    void clickedActive(){
      if(mouseX > x && mouseX < x+tWidth && mouseY > y-tHeight && mouseY < y){

         if(active == false){      //if already inactive (default)
           titleColor = 140;       //make gray
           active = true;          //set active
           collapsed = false;
           expandChildren();
         }else if(active == true){ //if already active
           titleColor = 0;         //make black
           active = false;         //set inactive
           collapsed = true;
           collapseChildren();
         }

      }
    }

    void expandChildren(){
       for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
         //this.children[i].collapsed = false;
         this.children[i].y = y + 150 + 150*i;
         println("expand");
       }
    }

    void collapseChildren(){
       for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
         //this.children[i].collapsed = true;
         println("collapse");
       }
    }

}
```

NODES.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>

    <type></type>
    <title>ROOT</title>
    <description></description>
    <image></image>

    <child>
        <type></type>
        <title>Test Child 1</title>
        <description></description>
        <image></image>

        <child>
            <type></type>
            <title>Test Child 1b</title>
            <description></description>
            <image></image>
        </child>
    </child>

    <child>
        <type></type>
        <title>Test Child 2</title>
        <description></description>
        <image></image>

        <child>
            <type></type>
            <title>Test Child 2b</title>
            <description></description>
            <image></image>
        </child>
    </child>

</root>
```

Comment: Processing is a paint-and-forget language. You can't "undraw" things, you simply draw more things on top of what you already had (or you clear the entire canvas and the start with a fresh sheet).

Comment: This question was already answered in a crosspost [here](http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/4965/problems-undrawing-objects#Item_5).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `background()` (or a `rect()` or an `image()` with size equal to your window's dimensions) before you draw anything, so that past frames get "hidden" behind the new ones.

Like this:

```
void draw() {
  background(0); // will set the background to black
  current.display(); //starts inactive, null collapsed
  if (current.collapsed == false) {
    for (int i = 0; i < current.children.length; i++) {
      current.children[i].display();
    }
  }
}
```